# Inuit TimeActivity Create: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: api, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to test my ability to import TimeActivity records and even when using the sample Create Request XML for TimeActivity I get an error:

Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 - Error report

## HTTP Status 400 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.23

below is my sample xml create request (pulled from https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/timeactivity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TimeActivity xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo"     xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
<TxnDate>2011-08-03-07:00</TxnDate>
<NameOf>Vendor</NameOf>
<Vendor>
<VendorIdidDomain="QBO">3793</VendorId>
</Vendor>
<CustomerId>3794</CustomerId>
<ItemId>3</ItemId>  
<ClassId>1</ClassId>  
<StartTime>2011-08-30T11:45:00-07:00</StartTime>
<EndTime>2011-08-30T13:15:00-07:00</EndTime>  
<Taxable>true</Taxable>
<HourlyRate>10.5</HourlyRate>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
<Hours>10</Hours>
<Minutes>5</Minutes>
<Description>This is a Description</Description>
</TimeActivity>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Sharing a sample TimeActivity create request. Please check other reference attributes like Vendor, Class etc. It should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TimeActivity xmlns='http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2'>
<TxnDate>2012-08-30-07:00</TxnDate>
<NameOf>Employee</NameOf>
<Employee>
    <EmployeeId>11</EmployeeId>
</Employee>
<CustomerId>2</CustomerId>
<JobId>4</JobId>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
<HourlyRate>50.0</HourlyRate>
<StartTime>2012-08-30T11:45:00-07:00</StartTime>
  <EndTime>2012-08-30T13:15:00-07:00</EndTime>
<Description/>
</TimeActivity>
```

Comment: Manas,

Thanks for the answer but the sample I provided is directly from Intuit's API explorer sample and that does not even work. So either the sample on Intuit's website is wrong or I am doing something wrong. Either way I need to know specifically what to change. Is Intuit missing something in its sample or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

There should be couple of small changes in the sample request ( We will update the doc )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TimeActivity xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo"     xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
<NameOf>Vendor</NameOf>
<Vendor>
<VendorId idDomain="QBO">5</VendorId>
</Vendor>
<CustomerId>2</CustomerId>
<ItemId>3</ItemId>  
<Taxable>true</Taxable>
<HourlyRate>10.5</HourlyRate>
<BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
<Hours>10</Hours>
<Minutes>5</Minutes>
<Description>This is a Description</Description>
</TimeActivity>
```

First replace all the reference values with the same of your test data.
For ex - VendorId, Class, Item and Customer

There are two bugs in the sample request.

```
 1. There should be a space between 'VendorId' and 'idDomain' ( Ref -5th line of the req )
 2. According to the doc,  " Either method of indicating duration can be entered, but not both. Hours/Minutes OR StartTime/EndTime is required."
    So plz remove any one of these. ( I've removed StartTime/EndTime )
    Otherwise you'll get the error which you have mentioned above.
    That is - Response code 400, Error msg - TIME_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_DURATION_TYPES_PRESENT
```

Please let us know if the above changes work for you.

Comment: Manas,
Thank you for the information! This should work perfectly. I will test and mark your response as answered as soon as I get a chance to verify.

Comment: Manas,

I am sorry to say that the sample you provided was not successful. Now I just get a server error:

**bold**<FaultInfo xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd">
  <Message>Internal Server Error</Message>
  <ErrorCode>500</ErrorCode>
  <Cause>SERVER</Cause>
</FaultInfo>**bold**

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same XML in Api Explorer. It worked fine for me. PFB snapshot. Please check if you are facing any encoding issue.

Please let me know if it works for you.

[image]